# When will eigenvalues of a matrix be positive?

Tags: linear-algebra

This may be very general question, Are there any set of conditions that if some arbitrary matrix say A fulfils we can say that A will have eigenvalues such that all of them are non negative. In other words what are conditions for a matrix to be positive semi definite.

Regards
Ahsan

Comment: There is also [Silvester's criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_criterion).

Comment: @AlexR That is what the link is pointing to.

Comment: @Pp.. Sorry, I overlooked the last sentence in the article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $A\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is positive semidefinite (All eigenvalues have nonnegative real part) iff

- $x^H A x \ge 0 \qquad \forall x\in\mathbb  C^n$
- If all principal minor determinants are $\ge 0$. Principal minors are the Matrices $M_I = (a_{ij})_{i,j\in I}, \ I\subset \{1,\ldots,n\}$ where some rows and columns with the same index are removed.
- If the ODE $\dot x= -Ax, x(0) = x_0$ satisfies $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} x(t) = 0$ for all $x_0 \in \mathbb C^n$
  The system is called stable in this case.

If $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is symmetric ($A=A^T$), it only has real eigenvalues and we can weaken condition 1 to $x^T A x \ge 0 \ \forall x\in\mathbb R^n$

**Note that $A\succeq 0$ (positive semidefinite) *is not equivalent to all eigenvalues being nonnegative***! A real matrix *can have complex eigenvalues* if it's not symmetric. In this case you need to require $\Re (\lambda_i) \ge 0$ (the real part). For symmetric matrices, this coincides.

Comment: This definition of positive semidefinite does not imply positive eigenvalues.  We must either impose symmetry or allow $x \in \Bbb C^n$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I'm unsure about this...

Comment: Err, should there be a minus sign on the ODE example? Consider the 1D example $\dot{f}(t) = a f(t)$ with 1-by-1 "matrix" $a$.

Comment: @NickAlger Yes indeed, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @AlexR counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}
$$
Note that for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$, $x^TAx = x^Tx$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom $A$ has eigenvalues $1 \pm i$... Where's the problem?

Comment: Oh, I see... I interpreted "positive" as "real and positive" rather than "with positive real part".  I'm not sure if there's an issue, then.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom That's an issue with the OP's thought that $\mathrm{eig}(A) \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow A \succeq 0$^^

Comment: Well, that makes sense for the $\Bbb C^n$ definition of positive semidefinite.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You can define positive semidefiniteness in a much more general context and even restricted to cones. The universal definition for a bilinear form $A$ to be psd on a cone $K$ is
$$A[x,x] \ge 0 \quad \forall x\in K\setminus\{0\}$$

Comment: Found a counterexample:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&0}
$$
has eigenvalues $\frac{-1 \pm i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, but $x^TAx = |x_1|^2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20842/discussion-between-alexr-and-omnomnomnom).

Answer (score 0):

Start with the equation $Ax = ax$ for eigenvalue $a$ and eigenvector $x$ of a matrix $A$. Then multiply by the left with $x^T$. Other hint: $x^T x > 0$.